# JS: calculate savings based on last element of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've list of prices:

```
 prices =  [57, 69, 90, 108, 142, 216, 344, 459, 670, 1134]
```

I need to calculate the savings of the current element based on the last one.

```
savings = [39, 61, 68, 75, 81, 85, 87, 88, 90] #first element should be empty or dropped, as first element or **prices** doesn't have something to calculate savings on.
```

See image with exact values:

[image]

**Note**: I can calculate other metrics, like average, etc. But cannot think of a way of using map or something to calculate based on last item on a list.

```
   var sum = prices.reduce(function (sum, value) {
          return sum + value;
        }, 0);

   alert("SUM: " + sum);

   var avg = sum / prices.length;

   alert("AVG: " + avg);

   var diffs = prices.map(function (value) {
            var diff = value - avg;
            return diff;
   });

   alert(diffs);
```

Comment: `anArray.slice(0).pop()` will give you the last one, without changing the original array

Comment: what do you mean by "savings based on the last one" can you give me an example?

Comment: Basically, he's looking at the *unit cost* of each item and then calculating the savings from the previous one. For example, the first item has a unit cost of $1.14, the next one $0.69. Therefore, the cost savings is (1.14 - 0.69)/1.14 = 0.39. (I.e., depends on the previous unit cost)

Comment: He means to say based on "first element of a list"

Comment: if you need the last element of a list you can do array[array.length -1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Savings is based on the item cost of the first compared to the unit cost of the others.

So

```
percentage of savings = (1 - UnitCost / BaseUnitCost) * 100
```

So using map to calculate the saving, skipping the first index since that is the base unit.

```js
var prices = [57, 69, 90, 108, 142, 216, 344, 459, 670, 1134]
var quantity = [50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000]
var min = prices[0]/quantity[0]
var savings = prices.map((v, i) => i ? `Save ${Math.round((1-(v/quantity[i])/min)*100)}%` : '')
console.log(savings)
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty elegant way using the map function.

Answer (score 1):

You want to first calculate the unit costs based on quantities and prices, then from the initial unit cost, calculate the savings:

```
function calcUnitCosts(quantities, prices){
    if( quantities.length != prices.length ) throw 'Array sizes unequal';
    var unitCosts = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++ ){
       unitCosts.push(prices[i] / quantities[i]);
    }
    return unitCosts;
}

function calcCostSavings(baseUnitCost, remainingUnitCosts){
    var costSavings = [];
    remainingUnitCosts.forEach((unitCost) => {
        costSavings.push((baseUnitCost - unitCost)/baseUnitCost)
    })
    return costSavings;
}

costSavings = calcCostSavings(unitCosts[0], unitCosts.slice(1))
```